# Optimize SQL Select Command

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there anyway to speed this up by optimizing/condensing the code?

```
SELECT fullName,
       email_address,
       pos_desc,
       EXT
FROM   dbo.BTC_WEB_EMPLOYEE_VIEW
WHERE  grp_cde = 'STAFF'
        OR grp_cde = 'PROF'
        OR grp_cde = 'EXEC'
        OR grp_cde = 'ADMIN'
        OR grp_cde = 'FAC'
ORDER  BY last_name
```

Comment: Are you sure about `dbo` and [tag:mysql]? Looks like [tag:sqlserver] instead...

Comment: Well, you could put an index on grp_code in the table (if there isn't one already), but that's changing the database structure, not the code itself.

Comment: check if there's an index on grp_Cde, and if not, add one and run it again.

Comment: This comes from ASP page SelectCommand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use IN instead of OR

```
SELECT fullName, email_address, pos_desc, EXT 
FROM dbo.BTC_WEB_EMPLOYEE_VIEW 
WHERE grp_cde IN ( 'STAFF', 'PROF', 'EXEC', 'ADMIN', 'FAC') 
ORDER BY last_name
```

may be this can help
or use index on this column

Comment: Substituting `OR` with `IN` does not affect query execution. It is just different syntacsis.